# Asus Q-LED: green and white are on even without boot media or video card installed

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard

When I start the pc, I see the red led (cpu) on for a short period, after the yellow one (dram) goes on for a short period, after the white light (vga) keeps on and after the green light (boot) keeps on. Than nothing happens any more, white and green led keep on.

- I also connected a buzzer (pc speaker): no beeps at all.
- When connecting a monitor trough DisplayPort -> black screen (I guess connection but no signal).

**What I tried to analyse the problem:**

- I disconnect the GeForce (pci-e) -> same problem
- I disconnect the M.2 disk -> same problem
- Tested the CPU in another pc -> works perfectly
- Tried to update the BIOS with the Asus Flashback function to the latest version, after I initialise the update, the status light keeps on and nothing happens.

**What can I do to analyse and solve this problem?**

---

- mobo: Asus ROG Z490-G
- cpu: Intel i7 10700
- dram: Kingston 32GB HyperX fury DDR4 CL16
- stor: Kingston A2000 SSD 1TB
- gpu: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1050 Ti D5 4G

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, but the problem was the connection from the monitor to the motherboard. It was connected with a DisplayPort cable which for some reason did not work. When i found a HDMI cable, the problem was solved. To the white led is on also when there is no connection! I thought it was an on board gpu error.

So hdmi saved me!

Comment: I got the same - stuck on White on Asus QLED on a new Asus Z790-A board. The Displayport cable that I use did not work. I had to change to HDMI.

There is nothing wrong with the Display Port cable, but the Asus MB does not boot if I use DP - only if I use HDMI.